# can´t get scaling to work properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I'm trying to create a lightbulb using a tutorial on youtube, and I am completely new to Blender.

I'm trying to tighten the bottom of the lightbulb by scaling it down, but it doesn't scale proportionally. Instead it wavers off to the side.

What I have so far:

[image: scr-current]

Expected result (screenshot from the tutorial):

[image: scr-tutorial]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click this icon and select Median point.

Read more here : [Pivots](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html)